# Html BeginForm in html helpers Issue MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

I am newly migrating my Project MVC 2 to MVC 5. I am struggling to create the BeginForm in my Views. If I create the BeginForm, it is not working.

```
  <div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Search" }))
    {
<form class="search-form" action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-success"/>
    </div>
 </form>
    }
    </div>
```

But when i click submit button it is nothing. how to use begin form in mvc ? Please help me.

Comment: is the button not clickable, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: Remove form tag in your code.

Comment: Because you have nested forms which is invalid html and not supported. Remove the inner `<form class="search-form" action="#">` element

Answer (score 0):

You are putting form within form.
Try below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Search", new { id = "Search" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-success"/>
</div>
}
```

Comment: try by adding:-   @using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Search", ormMethod.Post, new { id = "Search" })){ <!--you html-->}. Check name of your action and controller. Also debug

Answer (score 0):

I used the submit button under btn groups class. So it is not take it as a submit button. It just take it as a normal button

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-success"/>
</div>
```

I removed the `<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">` then i tried. It worked exactly..